# Using "open in new tab" fails to post data, debugging XHR requests with Chrome 'Developer Tools'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug an ajax request that POSTs data by inspecting the output of the request. The 'network' tab fails me as it states, "Failed to load response data" - I assume since it's a stacktrace and not JSON as expected.

Not a problem though, I figure I'll just take that XHR request and open it up in a new tab where I can browse over the dumped data. I right click and choose 'Open in new tab'. The new tab opens up but I get an error instead of my dump because the request did not include the POST data.

My workaround is to use the 'Copy as cURL' option and then paste that into my terminal. I don't like the extra step and depending what the output is it's hard to decipher in an ANSI terminal.

Is Google trying to "protect" me from resubmittal? Does the 'Replay XHR' context menu option do anything? Seems to do nothing for me. This is a pet peeve I wondered if others had experienced. Workarounds? Live with it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I"m having the same issue. "Replay XHR" doesn't do anything at all on a simple GET request.

Comment: My issue turned out to be service workers. I turned our apps service worker off and it finally allowed me to replay requests

Comment: Ahh. Related but different issue perhaps? Service workers are really a whole other beast I feel like. I'm sure tools have improved for debugging that layer of late. Not something I'm too up to speed on though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My current workaround is to use the new [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/).

The web console / developer tools work better in my opinion. Specifically I can open an Xhr request from the network tab in a 'new tab' and the POST data carries over to that new tab allowing me to simply refresh the page and replay the POST. Back to coding productively!

Comment: Awesome find, works great for me as well.

Comment: How can I do that? My Firefox Developer edition converts POST request to GET.